# Why low current in 3 watt green led in series and parallel

Tags: led

Why LEDs draw 3 times less current?
3 watt Green LED, 3 in series and 8 in parallel. Used computer 12V SMPS (measures 11.7V).
But current drawn is only 1.2A by entire circuit. Used shortest power wires around 1 meter, LEDs are soldered pin to pin to avoid resistance.
Each led is rated at 750mA. Voltage across each led measures around 3.4V.
No constant current circuit used, directly driven to test the current for 3 seconds.

[image]

Comment: You should read the data sheet for the LED and, if you don't understand what the forward voltage means, ask here and, link the data sheet.

Comment: If you get the datasheet, or make your own plot of V vs I curve, then you should understand.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have a constant current circuit the LED current will be determined by the LED characteristics, the voltage (and, to some extent, the chip temperature).

If the voltage is a bit too low for the (compound) LED characteristics you will get rather low current (your situation). If the voltage is a bit too high, the LED assembly will draw excessive current and can fail prematurely (maybe almost instantly).

From [here](https://components101.com/diodes/1-watt-led) is a typical LED characteristic curve. The exact numbers are not important (they'll vary by LED construction), the shape is important:

[image]

With 3 in series and 8 in parallel the LED would draw about 8 * 225mA = 1.8A at 3*3.2 = 9.6V. Increase the voltage by only 0.1V and the current goes up to 2.5A. Self-heating will cause the current to further increase.

Modern green LEDs tend to have a bit higher voltage drop at a given current and power level than blue/white LEDs such as the above example. Which is what you are seeing.

The problem with using constant voltage is that LED characteristics vary a lot (as well as with temperature) and typically the supplier will only guarantee a wide range of forward voltage so you cannot predict easily what voltage will give a reasonable current and what will be too dim or what will be damaging to the LED. So usually we use an LED driver which produces a constant current output, or at least a series resistor (though the latter wastes a lot of power compared to a switching type LED driver if it's a high power LED).

Comment: I will add constant current circuit later after I get minimum current conditions at least 3 amps. CC is not in the circuit now as I have to test the max current drawn. The computer XT smps shows 11.7 V. Each led drop around 3.3 to 3.4 (varies for each led characteristics )

Comment: Seems like you'll need more voltage than the supply is delivering.

Comment: voltage measured at leds input shows 9.9 V when they are on , while smps gives 11.7 Volts , wires of smps are just 15cm long . Too much drop for 15 cm length.

Comment: What gauge of wire do you have?

Comment: General guage as used in xt smps , could be 0.4 mm diameter

Comment: That would require tens of A. Now it sounds like an issue with bad connection or poorly crimped connector or maybe a measurement error.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your arrangement to allow higher voltage per string. Use 12 parallel sets of 2 in series.  Each 2 in series should have a current-limiting resistor.

2 series => total forward voltage is 2 * 3.4V = 6.8V
11.7V - 6.8V = 4.9V across resistor
Let's just use 200mA to start.
4.9V / 0.2A = 24.5 ohms
4.9V * 0.2A = 0.98 Watts

So, for each two-LED string, try four 100 ohm resistors in parallel, each 0.25W.  (A total of 4*12 = 48 hot 100-ohm resistors!)

You really need to use a Buck converter, or other DC-to-DC converter, for efficiency reasons, so as to not make so much heat and waste so much energy.  There is also a possibility of Boost converter, 12V * 2 = 24V / 3 = 8, so three parallel strings of 8 LED's in series.

Unfortunately the forward voltage of your green LED's doesn't match well with your power supply to use dropper resistors, especially at 750mA. Three LED's in series is too much forward voltage, and two LED's in series is not enough forward voltage (too wasteful for resistors).

Comment: The OP has not responded with additional information about the excessive voltage drop between the SMPS and the LEDs. And the premise of wanting to test maximum current by applying a fixed voltage with no current regulation seems fatally flawed from the beginning.

Comment: @PStechPaul - What do you mean?  I'm not sure that I understand.

Comment: In the comments posted to @SpehroPefhany's answer, the OP revealed that they were getting a voltage drop of 1.8 V over 15 cm of wire from the 11.7 V SMPS to the LEDs. presumably at 1.2 amps. If that problem was resolved, it's likely that the LEDs drew excessive current and failed, which may be why the OP has not responded. Your answer is valid, but impractical, and your suggestion of a buck or boost circuit would be the way to go. Or just series inductors with diodes and PWM drive.

Comment: @PStechPaul - The OP commented under Spehro's answer, and said, "I will add constant current circuit later after I get minimum current conditions at least 3 amps. CC is not in the circuit now as I have to test the max current drawn."  I wanted to show both that three LED's in series is too much forward voltage under her 11.7V supply at her desired current, and that testing her 750mA per LED output level may be impractical with the linear solution, in this case current-limiting resistors. So I agree with you, but the OP says we are going this way, so I'm doing the best I can.

Comment: @PStechPaul I will test as per your suggestions for the 3.4 volt 3 watt button Led . Now I am trying with everbrite cob leds 3 watt (9 to 12v ) 5 watt (12v to 14v ) , 7 watt etc . Now they come in dozens of configurations which are a mess .

Comment: @HarshitaKapur - You said, "[to] PStechPaul I will test as per your suggestions for the 3.4 volt 3 watt button Led".  Did you test? Please let us know...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to drive strings of 3 LEDs having forward voltages of 3.2 and 3.3 V, from an 11.7 V power source. The PWM is 5 kHz with a duty cycle of about 80%. I used two different inductors to somewhat match the current, using the same duty cycle for both strings.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMkUXO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here are the waveforms:

[image: PWM voltages]

[image: LED string currents]

Note that the current for D2 is still rising at 10 ms. This is continuous conduction mode which is very sensitive to duty cycle.

I ran another simulation at 40 kHz with 50 uH inductors, which works in discontinuous conduction mode, for 9.6V and 10.2V zeners (simulating strings of 3.2 to 3.4 V), and the average current is reasonably constant. Here are waveforms:

[image: PWM voltages]

[image: LED currents]